# Loop for variables changing the name of the dateframe

Tags: r, loops

I have a set of data frames that are different only in the termination of their name: imp1, imp2...imp20

I want to perform a transformation of one variable with the same name in each of these
data frames. If I write:

```
for (i in 1:20) {
  item <- paste0("imp", i)
  item$numenf<-item$sqrnumenf*item$sqrnumenf
numSummary(item[,c("numenf")], 
           statistics=c("mean", "sd", "quantiles", "skewness", "kurtosis"), 
           quantiles=c(0,.25,.5,.75,1), type="2")
item$sqrnumenf<-NULL 
}
```

I get the following error:

*`Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`*

Any idea?

Thank you,

Ángel

Comment: you need `get()`. Perhaps `get(paste0(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given in the comments by Richard Telford is correct, but I want to add a little more to it.

The value of `item <- paste0("imp", i)` is just the characters `"imp1"`.
The **object** `imp1` must be retrieved using `get()`, which takes a string as input, and retrieves the associated object from your environment.

However, this works **both ways** - if you assign `item$sqrnumenf <- NULL`, nothing will happen to `imp1`. That is because there is no direct link between `item` and `imp1`. We are able to `get()` the `imp1` object by name, and in the same fashion we are able to `assign()` it a value. However, you need to assign it the **full object**, as you can't assign a column. `assign(obj_name$value, NULL)` won't work, as there is no `$value`-column in `obj_name`, only in its associated object.

Thus, you need to first edit `item` to your needs, and then assign the new `item` to the object named `obj_name`.

Here is an example that builds on your comment:

```r
# Using base R
imp1 <- data.frame(value = runif(10))
imp2 <- data.frame(value = runif(10))
for (i in 1:2) {
  obj_name = paste0("imp", i)
  item <- get(obj_name)
  item$valuesqr = item$value * item$value
  item$value = NULL
  assign(obj_name, item)
}

imp1
#>      valuesqr
#> 1  0.35679458
#> 2  0.09372996
#> 3  0.63121435
#> 4  0.42756713
#> 5  0.43187350
#> 6  0.07281334
#> 7  0.33401852
#> 8  0.67389063
#> 9  0.74741363
#> 10 0.50307369
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you both, but I'm afraid it doesn´t work. See a minimal reproducible example, that I have run without success: R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362) `sqrnumenf <- c(9, 9, 16, 0, 4, 1, 1, 1,1,0)
imp1 <- data.frame(sqrnumenf)
sqrnumenf <- c(4, 4, 9, 0, 4, 1, 1, 0,0,0)
imp2 <- data.frame(sqrnumenf)
for (i in 1:2) {
  obj_name = paste0("imp", i)
  item <- get(obj_name)
  item$sqrnumenf<-NULL 
}`

Comment: @Ángel, I have updated my answer with the addition of `assign()`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Not yet, @mhvod, sorry. This is what I would need according to your example, and the message I get: `imp1 <- data.frame(value = runif(10))
imp2 <- data.frame(value = runif(10))
for (i in 1:2) {
  obj_name = paste0("imp", i) # Create the name dynamically
  item <- get(obj_name)       # Get the associated object
  item$valuesqr<-item$value*item$value  # Transform the variable
  assign(obj_name$value, NULL)      # Assign the variable value to NULL
}`                      Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: This is because you are using assign wrong, I have updated my answer to reflect how it works now :)

Comment: Ok. The most important part is working and I thank you for that. I'm trying to include `mean(item$valuesqr)` in the loop, but wherever I write it I don´t get the mean of the newly calculated variable. Why is that?

Comment: If you were to add it to the loop, you would have to add it after `item$valuesqr = item$value * item$value`. Note that in the loop the output of `mean()` and other base functions will usually be suppressed. As such, you need to explicitly `print()` or `cat()` the output. For example, you can add `cat("Mean of", obj_name, "is:", mean(item$valuesqr))`

Comment: I didn´t know I had to explicitly 'print()' in a loop. It worked like a charm now. Thank you again, @mhvod, for your time and effort

Comment: You are very welcome - not everything is straight-forward in R, so don't hesitate to ask. :)